# How loose are cam and crank shafts when timing belt is off?

Tags: timing, camshaft, crankshaft, crank

I'm trying to figure out how my crankshaft could be slightly off, during a belt and tensioner replacement (K7M engine).

In fitting the tensioner, is it possible the two shafts could have gotten out of alignment without me noticing?

The vehicle is in 1st gear and the spark plugs have not been removed. Although I'm not sure if I removed the locking pin while I was replacing and setting the tensioner.

Answer (score 2):

In most engines the camshaft will move on its own when the chain or belt is removed.  This is due to pressure from the valve springs on the cam lobes.

The engine's service manual should have the procedure for either locking the cams into place during service and/or re-timing the engine after removing and replacing the cams or cam drives.